# How to override Django base template

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to extend the base template for a page in my Django application, but there are a few HTML elements that I need to exclude from this new page that is in the base. What is the best way to remove them? Do I just delete the elements with JQuery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use template blocks to achieve this. For example, in base.html, surround the HTML elements in a named block:

```
{% block a_unique_name %}<div>This is only relevant in base.html</div>{% endblock %}
```

The HTML in the block will be used only if no other template overrides it. You can override it in your sub-template like this:

```
{% extend base.html %}
{% block a_unique_name %}{% endblock %}
```

Now the value from sub-template will be used and will override the default value from base.html.

Answer (score 0):

Create base template without these elements. Create child template with these elements. Inherit all the pages form this child template and this particular page — from base template.

Another way is to put these elements into the block in base template.

```
{# base template #}
{% block override_me %}
<elem1 /><elem2 />
{% endblock %}

{# child template #}
{% block override_me %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is not necessarily a bad idea. If the code must be recreated in several sub-templates just to avoid putting it in base.html, it violates the DRY principle. Using blocks is better.

Comment: @George Cummins Removing elements with JS is not necessarily a bad idea? Ooook. And please show where DRY is violated (note, that this approach is used in [django site](https://github.com/django/djangoproject.com/tree/master/django_website/templates), for example).

Comment: Apparently I was unclear as to which part of the original question your "bad idea" comment was directed toward. Removing elements in child templates is not a problem, but I agree that removing elements via JS is less than ideal. If you re-work the first paragraph of your answer, I can remove my downvote.

Comment: @George Cummins And i think my first variation is still better, if you need to remove some elements of the base template, it's the first sign that there's something wrong with your template organisation.